# How do I slide(scroll) an entire div thats been retrieved through jquery's .load()?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, scroll, slide

So I have I this javascript that loads into a div the contents of my php (which gets data from a mysql database). When a different button is clicked, it calls the eat.php file again, with the new data to retrieve from MySQL and again loads the new data into the div.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("a[name=eat]").click(function() {
        $("div.nav a[name=eat]").css({"background-color":"#666966","color":"#fff"});
        $(".user-main").load("eat.php");
    });
    $("a[name=analyze]").click(function() {
        $(".user-main").load("eat.php",{ name: "John", time: "2pm" });
    });
});
</script>
```

And that is ok and everything. My question is how can I make this "slide" into the new div, like it's being scrolled horizontally? I am having no luck with the animate feature in jQuery, and would prefer not to use any frameworks. Also, is the correct way to check for a jQuery post by doing:

```
if (isset($_POST['name']))
```

in my eat.php file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quite sure what you are asking. 
If you want to ensure the data you have just added is scrolled into view, then you can use code like this

```
if (document.all) {
document.body.scrollIntoView(false);
} else {
    document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd','<a name="' + a + '"><\/a>');
window.location.hash = '#'+a;
}
```

The trick with insertAdjacentHTML is inserting a label into the screen and then telling the browser to jump to it. The label is the contents of a javascript variable which must be different each time the code is run.

If you wish to slide a whole division into view, then you will have to use a timer. Set up the div so the over-flow is hidden and it is positioned off screen, using position relative and large top or left/right values.  Then, each time the timer goes off, decrease the offset towards zero.

If the timer goes off every 50ms and you move only a few pixels, you will get 20fps and it will appear quite smooth.